# How to detect "socket closed while connection is open" error in pika?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pika

I'm using pika to receive message from rabbitmq. If a connection had  been left unused for a long period, when I start to use it again, I found "Socket closed while connection is open" error in log, but no error will been thrown. You cannot detect this problem by checking "BlockingConnection.is_close" attribute either.

I wrote codes trying to reestabilsh connection if "is_close" is true, but it didn't work. Then my script will be blocked at channel.consume() method because the problem described above cannot be detected.

```
 while True:
            try:
                if mainStatus.status == SERVING: # my program status. In this case it should start serving.
                    if connection.is_closed:
                        connection.close()
                        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
                        ch = connection.channel()
                        ch.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True)

                    for message in ch.consume(queue_name,inactivity_timeout=1):
                        if message:
                            method, properties, body=message
                        else:
                            method, properties, body=None,None,None
                        if mainStatus.status!=SERVING:
                            if method: mainStatus.ch.basic_nack(method.delivery_tag)
                            break
                        elif method is not None:# Serving and receive a message
                           serve_a_message(mainStatus.ch,db,method,properties,body)
                        else:# normal timeout
                            continue
......
```

I expect to detect "Socket closed" error by checking "is_close" or by catching exception, but nothing happened except error message in log.

Comment: What is logged by your AMQP broker? If you're using RabbitMQ, my guess is that it closes the connection due to missed heartbeats. If your code blocks Pika's I/O loop it can't sent heartbeat messages.